# Should not stackapps.com use the same closing reasons used on this very site?

Tags: support, close-reasons, stackapps

I was flagging a question on stackapps.com that asked about the differences between API 1.1 and API 2.0 to close it because it is too broad, and I noticed the site is still using "noise or pointless" as closing reason.

> This question does not add anything useful; having it present on the site is actively harmful because it distracts from other more useful questions.

[image: screenshot]

Should not the site use the same closing reasons used by Meta Stack Overflow? "Not constructive" seems a better closing reason than one suggesting the question is, "harmful because it distracts from other more useful questions."